# cannot run docker build when using docker setup from Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2022

I created a web-project named `ProjectService` and added docker-support for it using Visual Studio 2022. I can build and debug the image pretty well from within VS.

Now I try to build and run the image from the command-line in order to have it within my build-pipeline. So I execute this from the root-directory of my repo:

```
docker build -t myrep/demo:latest ./ProjectService
```

However when I do that I get the following error:

> #11 ERROR: "/ProjectService/ProjectService.csproj" not found: not found
>
> #12 [build 4/8] COPY [DatabaseManager/DatabaseManager.csproj, DatabaseManager/]
> #12 sha256:b881c00e01ebb7ea687c2f8c5d5f585e237bf6151b63cd21110ed1a7bdf74af6
> #12 ERROR: "/DatabaseManager/DatabaseManager.csproj" not found: not found

I think this is because within my docker-file paths are relative:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ProjectService/ProjectService.csproj", "ProjectService/"]
COPY ["DatabaseManager/DatabaseManager.csproj", "DatabaseManager/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ProjectService/ProjectService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ProjectService"
RUN dotnet build "ProjectService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectService.dll"]
```

when I execute `docker` from within the `ProjectService`-drectory itself, I get the same error, though.

My folder-structure is this:

```
root
  ProjectService
    ProjectService.csproj
    DockerFile
  DatabaseManager
    DatabaseManager.csproj
```

where `ProjectService` depends on `DatabaseManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile looks like it assumes that the build context is the root directory.

So to build it you can either do it from the root directory with

```
docker build -t myrep/demo:latest -f ProjectService/Dockerfile .
```

or from the ProjectService directory with

```
docker build -t myrep/demo:latest ..
```

A 3rd option is to move the Dockerfile to the root directory. Then your Dockerfile will be in the directory that's assumed to be the build context. That's how most projects are organized. Then you can build with

```
docker build -t myrep/demo:latest .
```